# Rest API in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rest, synchronous

I need to use Rest API in my app. But I need to do it compatible with iOS 3.0.
I need synchronous framework with object mapping (like in RestKit) and without blocks . May be somebody known something like that?

Comment: Why compatible with iOS 3? Even the iPhone 3G can run iOS 4, and iOS 3 is just outdated. I would say that, if your users won't update, I wouldn't support them.

Comment: I known it, but consumer want possibility to use iPhone 1 generation, where latest iOS is 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my problem in Objective Resource library. It not develop now, but it have all features i need with comparability iOs 3.2.

Answer (score -2):

Try this -

```
  NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString* bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[userDefaults removePersistentDomainForName:bundleIdentifier];
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @nanjunda [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) != reset. But you made me laugh.

Comment: i didnt noticed it .. sorry :(

Comment: @nanjunda you should delete this answer